# After running less command in -bash, instead of a prompt, I get "(END) ". What's happening, and how do I get the prompt again?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, less

I run the bash command "less" on a .txt. After printing out the lines in the file, the name of the file and "(END) " is printed. But I do not get a command prompt again.

Other than closing the terminal window and opening a new one, I don't know how to proceed.

So, how do I move past this "(END) " to get a prompt?

Comment: Press `h` to see help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `less` reaches the end of the file, it displays `(END)`. Just hit <kbd>Q</kbd> to return to the prompt.

For general reference, in the *nix world <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will stop the current process, that will also return you to the terminal (though this does not work for `less` as you found out). Alternatively, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to send the current process to the background. You can then bring it back with `fg`. See `help fg` and `help bg` for details.

Oh and `less` is not a `bash` command, it is a program in its own right and has nothing to do with `bash`.

Comment: I tried Ctrl C, but that doesn't seem to work in this case. But 'Q' did the trick. Thank you for that, and the less vs bash clarification.

Comment: See also: [what to do when ctrl-c can't kill a process?](http://superuser.com/questions/243460/what-to-do-when-ctrl-c-cant-kill-a-process)