# Aborted (core dumped) after breaking a python progrm

Tags: python3

I was following [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/243460/what-to-do-when-ctrl-c-cant-kill-a-process), and released a python program running on my console using the combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>. Now, each time I try to run this program I am getting:

> Aborted (core dumped)

I am new to this and I am not sure how to mend this.

Comment: CTRL+Z suspends the process. It is still active and could be locking system resources the new instance also wants to lock. // What does the application do? Why could you not interrupt it? If all else fails: Reboot.

Comment: Is there a way I can locate the process ID now that it is locked?